# ListView with Mono Android - Setting checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, mono

I'm having an issue accessing a checkbox inside a ListView.
I'm trying to set the checkbox on creation of each View.

I made a custom adapter implementing this function:

```
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemChecked, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position]._fName + items[position]._lName;

        // This seems to return null.. I'm probably accessing it the wrong way.
        view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Android.Resource.Id.Checkbox).Checked = items[position]._Enabled;
        return view;
    }
```

Problem is that, as the comment state, the program throws a System.NullReferenceException.
Point is that I have no clue how to access the checkbox otherwise.

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: please post your full code.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I was able to fix the issue (few days ago, forgot to reply here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to proceed, yet it worked for me:
Considering we know the list will consist of a text and a checkbox, I casted straight to a CheckedTextView..

```
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView as CheckedTextView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemChecked, null) as CheckedTextView;
        view.SetText(items[position]._fName + items[position]._lName, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        view.Checked = items[position]._Enabled;

        return view;
    }
```

It might not be the right/best way to achieve this but at least it works..